# I am writing a code in java to check whether the sides (which are already given) are either equilateral, isoceles or scalene

Tags: java

```java
public class Triangle
{
  public static void main (String []args)
  {
    int a =10, b=20, c=30;
    if (a == b && b == c)
    {
      System.out.println("Equilateral");
    }
    if (a == b && b != c)
    {
      System.out.println("Isoceles");
    }
    else if (a == c && c != b)
    {
      System.out.println("Isoceles");
    }
    else if (b == c && c!= a)
    {
      System.out.println("Isoceles");
    }
    else if (a != b && b!= c)
    {
      System.out.println("Scalene");
    }
  }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlhNg.jpg

I used "Decoder" to write the code.
The code doesn't seem to be correct but still it is executing correctly.
I am just a beginner in coding and wrote the program by myself but I amnot sure if this is the appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: Post the code in your question, not image of code!

Comment: Btw. what is "Decoder"?

Comment: Btw I am using this for the first time so I don't really know how to do that :( sorry.                          Decoder is an android app that helps to write codes in any programming languages.

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question. And note: please be more precise about your request. Is that code working, or do you have errors?

Comment: Well, then please visit the [help] center. There is plenty of documentation that explains to you how to write a good question, and how you can use the formatting tools and markup language to include code. That is the thing: when you are new in a place, you first have to spend some time to figure how it is working.

Comment: Oki thank you for the information. :) Will improve.

Comment: I am really sorry, I didn't read the instructions properly beforehand due to which the format on which question must have been asked isn't followed. I will improve next time whenever I will be asking some other questions. Once again, sorry for the inconvenience. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can regroup the conditions leading to the same outcome.
You can also use else if to exclude the previous case. If two sides are equal and it's not equilateral, it's isoceles and if not, it's scalene.

```
if (a == b && b == c) {
    System.out.println("Equilateral");
} else if (a == b || b == c || c == a) {
    System.out.println("Isoceles");
} else {
    System.out.println("Scalene");
}
```